# PostgreSQL - Split words (len>1) into rows with regexp_split_to_table

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying to split the following string into rows such that every word is in its own row with the exception of words of a single character (e.g. a, i):

```
"the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog"
```

This is what I've been messing with in SQL Fiddle, but I can't get the right result:

```
SELECT foo FROM regexp_split_to_table('the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog',  
  E'(\\s+)(?=\\w{2,})') AS foo;
```

The result:

```
the
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over a
lazy
dog
```

It's almost correct, but for some reason the a is being combined with over. I want to disregard the a completely.

What's the little thing I'm missing?

Comment: `SELECT foo FROM regexp_split_to_table('the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog', E'(?<=\\w{2,}) (?=\\w{2,})') AS foo;`?

Comment: `select regexp_split_to_table('the quick brown fox jumps over a i lazy dog',  '\s+(\w\s+)*');`

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you! Very nice.

Comment: I'm working with [`version 9.6`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/edc22/1) and that may just be the reason. I will delete my answer and urge @Abelisto to write his or hers.

Comment: I'm also working with 9.6, so I'm unsure what the issue is. I appreciate your help regardless!

Comment: The answer provided by @Abelisto is definitely better, but you could also use a subquery and test length of strings. Something like this `select a from (select regexp_split_to_table(a, '\s+') as a from t) as t where length(a) > 1`

Answer (score 4):

The one solution already provided in the comment:

```
select regexp_split_to_table('the quick brown fox jumps over a i lazy dog.', '\s+(\w\s+)*');
```

However it does not takes in account punctuation marks. So instead of splitting the string by delimiter(s) you cant to extract words from it using `regexp_matches()` function:

```
postgres=# select (regexp_matches('the quick brown fox;jumps over, a lazy dog.', '(\w{2,})', 'g'))[1];
-- or
postgres=# select unnest(regexp_matches('the quick brown fox;jumps over, a lazy dog.', '(\w{2,})', 'g'));
┌────────────────┐
│ regexp_matches │
╞════════════════╡
│ the            │
│ quick          │
│ brown          │
│ fox            │
│ jumps          │
│ over           │
│ lazy           │
│ dog            │
└────────────────┘
```